# Django CreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Can't figure out why `CreateView` doesn't return `HttpResponse`. For now, I use this view just for posting (no GET). I thought that set `self.success_url` should be enough (as you can see in `def post`).

```
class TripCreationView(CreateView):
    form_class = TripCreationForm
    template_name = 'frontend/homepage.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.success_url = request.POST.get('success_url') or reverse('frontend:homepage')
        super(TripCreationView, self).post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
    #
    # def form_valid(self, form):
    #     trip = form.save(self.request)
    #     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(TripCreationView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Do you know what to do?

Comment: you missed return statement before super in post block

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding `post` here anyway. That logic goes in the `get_success_url` method.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a return statement.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.success_url = request.POST.get('success_url') or reverse('frontend:homepage')
    return super(TripCreationView, self).post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```